# ¿Como hacer un select2 mas ancho?

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer un select2 mas ancho, ya que cuando lo meto dentro de un tab se hace chico.
Esta es la forma en como la construyo

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdFarmacia)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdFarmacia, new SelectList(ViewBag.Farmacias, "IdFarmacia", "Nombre_Farmacia"), "Seleccionar", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdFarmacia, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

Y este es mi JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IdFarmacia').select2();
    });
```

adjunto la imagen de como se ve dentro del tab 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi se ve fuera del tab

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Conoces hojas de estilo (CSS)?

Comment: Si, he trabajado un poco con hojas de estilo

Comment: Click, derecho, inspeccionar elemento y a ver qué estilos se aplican y cuáles no. Edita la pregunta, agrega tu CSS y el HTML generado por el framework

Comment: Select tiene un theme para bootstrap! https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.3.html de ahí en más lo manejas como el resto de tus select o inputs!